# Error: joplin: It seems the App source '/Applications/Joplin.app' is not there

Tags: homebrew

When I want to use brew to upgrade the system:

```
$ brew upgrade                                                                                                     ‹ruby-2.7.2›
==> Upgrading 1 outdated package:
sshfs 2.10_2 -> 3.7.3
Error: sshfs has been disabled because it requires closed-source macFUSE!
==> Casks with 'auto_updates true' or 'version :latest' will not be upgraded; pass `--greedy` to upgrade them.
==> Upgrading 1 outdated package:
joplin 2.1.8 -> 2.8.8
==> Upgrading joplin
==> Downloading https://github.com/laurent22/joplin/releases/download/v2.8.8/Joplin-2.8.8.dmg
Already downloaded: /Users/dolphin/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/b97405d6b948853d8d267346608a466e548c03db66761a82d528dbad1c9afd8f--Joplin-2.8.8.dmg
==> Purging files for version 2.8.8 of Cask joplin
Error: joplin: It seems the App source '/Applications/Joplin.app' is not there.
(base)
```

why did this happen? what should I do to fixed this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You installed an application "Joplin" previously using Brew. When you run `brew upgrade` it tries to upgrade things it's installed in the past. However, you must've deleted "Joplin", so Brew stops when it cannot find it.

If you don't want "Joplin," uninstall it using Brew to resolve the discrepancy:

```sh
brew uninstall joplin
```

If you do want "Joplin," then you should uninstall it to resolve the discrepancy, then fully reinstall it:

```sh
brew uninstall joplin
brew install joplin
```

You can also use `--force` to try upgrading it directly:

```sh
brew upgrade --force joplin
```